# Disable SVN checkout for external locations in NetBeans 7.3

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-7, svn-externals, svn-checkout

So here is the problem. When checking out SVN repository it completes it but then creates a new directory with the same name and checkouts everything in that. This recursive checkout process goes on forever. I'm using NetBeans and in output window it says:

```
Updating external location at: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectx/projectx
```

It should stop just at ...htdocs/projectx.

So my question is - how to turn off checkout for external locations in NetBeans? ...or ideally why is it checking out my project recursively and how to fix it?

Comment: I'd check what's wrong with the `svn:externals` property first. What's set on `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectx/` and `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip - reading through svn documentation right now. Just not sure I can delete that property safely..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so here is the solution I took:

```
svn propget -R svn:externals /path/to/working/copy/projectx/projectx
```

This shows all svn:externals properties in that directory. Figure out which is the broken one. In my case guilty was the root dir which had external link to nonexsistant sub-dir.
So I deleted the property:

```
svn propdel svn:externals /path/to/working/copy/projectx/projectx
```

Thats it.